# Syntax Error Popping Up Trying to Add Friendly Id Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I am a beginner and I'm currently following Mackenzie Child's Portfolio + Blog Rails Youtube tutorials to deploy a website on Heroku. You can find the link to the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62PQUaDhgqw&t=14s

I'm trying to add the friendly id gem but am running into this problem in my terminal:

```
Ivys-MacBook-Pro:portfolio ivychen$ Post.find_each(&:save)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

I don't know how to fix it. I think I might've not formatted the lines in my post.rb correctly, so here they are if you want to take a look:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#"}
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

This is what I've put in my post_controller.rb:

```
def find_post 
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is probably an easy fix, but I just don't know how to do it! Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your suntax seems wrong i would try `Post.find_each{ |post| post.save! }`

Comment: I got it going! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your rails project directory and run 'rails c' to enter the rails console where you can write ruby code with rails loaded up.

```
/rails/myproject $ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 81138
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> Post.find_each(&:save)
```

You're trying to evaluate ruby/rails code in bash (terminal) when you need to be in the rails console.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you soo much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should run `Post.find_each(&:save)` in rails console `rails c`

Comment: Got it! Thank you!